# Secure way of passing id_token in Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: security, azure, azure-ad-b2c

When using Azure Active Directory B2C, after authentication you will get the `id_token` to verify the user for future requests. There are few ways we can pass the `id_token` back to the user. ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc)) They are `query`, `form_post`, or `fragment`.

If we use query the `id_token` will be passed as a query parameter. Is there any security risk with this? If so how can I directly inject this to a cookie in the web browser?

Answer (score 3):

Form post is the most secure since it is not stored in browser history.

Query strings and fragments however are stored in the history, so someone could get it from there.

None are visible to anyone trying to man-in-the-middle the connection if the token is passed over HTTPS.

EDIT: It doesn't really matter when the id token expires, since it is not an access token. You can't use it to call anything. The only reason you want to secure it is because it contains private information about the user.

Your redirect URI where Azure AD B2C posts the token should be https:, not http:.

Comment: Even though the query string is stored in the history, if the token is getting expired after X minutes, it won't be a problem right. Also can you detail a bit on passing over HTTPS?

Comment: The only information I get from the server is id_token. How can I get the access token?

Comment: The id token tells your app who the user is. Access tokens you would need if you want to call e.g. the Azure AD Graph API as the user.